# C++ ifstream split w.r.t. a character

Tags: c++, split, char, iostream, ifstream

i would like to C++-read a file line by line, and split each line w.r.t to `"\t"` character so as to fill in a matrix. my code would go like this

```
    ifstream data_x;
        double** test_data = new double*[100];
        for(int j = 0 ; j <  ; j++)
             test_data[j] = new double[4]; 

    data_x.open("X.txt");

    int i = 0;
    if (data_x.is_open()) 
    {
        while (!data_x.eof()) 
        {
            char** split = data_x.split("\t") 
            for(int k = 1 ; k < 4 ; k++)
                 test_data[i][k];
            i++;
        }
    }

    data_x.close();

    ifstream data_y;
    data_y.open("Y.txt");

    i = 0;
    if (data_y.is_open()) 
    {
        while (!data_y.eof()) 
        {
            data_y >> test_data[i][0];
            i++;
        }
    }

    data_y.close();
```

where syntax

```
 char** split = data_x.split("\t") 
 for(int k = 1 ; k < 4 ; k++)
      test_data[i][k];
```

is approximative. how to make this properly with C++ ?

thanks

Comment: Use std::string, getline and the string library functions.

Comment: first, use std::string, then use boost string algorithms library to split each line.

Comment: Whenever I see `while (!data_x.eof())` I can guarantee that the following code is wrong. (It can be done correctly that way but there are much neater idioms so people that know don't use eof() in the test).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Splitting a string in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/splitting-a-string-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your file only contains numbers, here's the standard C++ idiom:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

std::ifstream infile("data.txt");

std::vector<std::vector<double>> matrix;

for (std::string line; std::getline(infile, line); )
{
     std::istringstream iss(line);
     std::vector<double> row;

     for (double d; iss >> d; )
     {
         row.push_back(d);
     }

     matrix.push_back(row);
}
```

If you know the size of the matrix, you can add the relevant `reserve` calls to avoid vector reallocations. You can also add tests for whether there was any unrecognized data on a line, but for now this should get you started.

Comment: I am hoping that the new Move functionality in C++11 covers that correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a vector out of entities separated by a whitespace is actually trivial:

```
std::vector<T> fields(
    std::istream_iterator<T>(
        d::istringstream(line) >> std::skipws),
    std:.istream_iterator<T>()));
```

If you cell type `T` is something which would consider other spaces than `'\t'` as separators you might want to change what is considered a space using a modified `std::ctype<char>` facet.

Obviously, the logic above can be packaged up in some easier to use finction.